# SoftLayer API error - setUserMetadata is not implemented

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am ordering SoftLayer VMs using API. Also, setting user metadata value. 
I have been using "softlayer-api-client-0.2.2.jar" to call various API.

setUserMetadata was working fine before. But since few days it is failing. 
is this API recently changed? is the above jar file version correct?

setUserMetadata API is giving below error -

Exception in thread "Thread-2" com.softlayer.api.ApiException$Internal: SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Strategy_Behavior_Standard::setUserMetadata is not implemented.(code: SoftLayer_Exception_NotImplemented, status: 500)

Kindly, help to get this issue fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I am able to set user metadata through [SoftLayer API Client for Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java), here a java script, try this and let me know if you continue having issues please. Make sure to use master branch from the client.

Script:

```
package com.softlayer.api.VirtualGuest;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * This script sets the data that will be written to the configuration drive.
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setUserMetadata
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2 (master branch)
 */
public class SetUserMetadata {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to set user metadata         
     */
    public SetUserMetadata() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Guest.Service guestService = Guest.service(client, new Long(206659875));

        // Setting the medatada
        String metadataTest = "test1RcvRcv";
        List<String> metadata = new ArrayList<String>();
        metadata.add(metadataTest);

        try {
            boolean result = guestService.setUserMetadata(metadata);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of SetUserMetadata method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SetUserMetadata();
    }
}
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::setUserMetadata](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setUserMetadata)